# Using JNI with a C function that returns multiple short int pointers whose size is not pre-determined

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I have a C function to be used in an Android app that "returns" multiple short (int) pointers and the number of short ints pointed to by each pointer via the parameter list. I want to return all these lists to the calling Java class, so can't use a single return type for the function. It seems that I need to know before hand the size of the list in order to pre-allocate a java short[] with enough memory as follows:

inside java class

```
short[] fooArr = new short[2];
short[] mooArr = FibLib.testFunc(fooArr);
```

inside c file

```
JNIEXPORT jshortArray JNICALL Java_com_funTest_testFunc(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jshortArray retData) {
// retData is the data returned to the caller via the parameter list
// it is declared in the java section and a pointer is created here
jshort outCArray[] = {100, 200};  // some fake data; in reality the size of this list is unknown until runtime 
jshort *cArray = (*env)->GetShortArrayElements(env, retData, NULL);
if (cArray == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    //jini len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);
    jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, retData);
    jint ix;
    for (ix = 0; ix < len; ix++) {
        cArray[ix] = outCArray[ix]; // this will modify retData with the new values when we release
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseShortArrayElements(env, retData, cArray, 0); // mode 0 to copy back the content and free cArray
}

jshortArray outJNIArray = (*env)->NewShortArray(env, 2);  // allocate
//if (NULL == outJNIArray) return -1;
(*env)->SetShortArrayRegion(env, outJNIArray, 0 , 2, outCArray);  // copy
return outJNIArray;
}
```

If I don't know the size of retData beforehand, how do I pass a "resizeable" fooArr to testFunc?

Answer (score 0):

> so can't use a single return type for the function.

Why not? The key to using JNI is to define your Java model (classes and public members) in a natural way. Some of the public members can be made native and implemented in JNI but it is often easier to create private native methods and helper methods so the JNI coding is cleaner and more natural to C.

If it makes sense for `com.funTest.testFunc` to be a factory method, creating instances of itself, add some instance fields to the class for the results, then, in JNI, create an instance and populate its fields.

Or, if you want a separate results class, define one and create it on the JNI side and return it.

It all depends on the Java model that works best.